# Computers, AI and ML leading to math discoveries or insight

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, machine-learning

Does anyone know of any other examples where computers, artificial intelligence or machine learning have led to mathematical discoveries or insights?

For example: [*DeepMind Helps Mathematicians Develop New Theorem in Potential Breakthrough*](https://gadgets.ndtv.com/science/news/deepmind-ai-mathematics-theorem-knots-oxford-sydney-university-google-2635296)

Also, is there any known research in these areas?

Here are some thoughts on research [*Advancing mathematics by guiding human intuition with AI*](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-021-04086-x)

Comment: FYI, a related MathOverflow post is [What are possible applications of deep learning to research mathematics?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/390174/129887).

Comment: @JohnOmielan: Thanks - I will certainly read / review that!